# Using Object interfaces in Magento modules

Tags: magento

Is it possible or advisable to use object interfaces in custom Magento modules and if so how would this fit in with Magento factory pattern etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any class/interface which is being subclassed will not be resolved through Magento factory methods; the definition will be loaded via the autoloader.

Beyond that, the rules and guidelines for abstract classes, interfaces, and general superclasses are the same.